# The number of users who can connect at a time?

Tags: agora.io

I would like to know the number of people allowed to make a connection at the same time on agora's vedio conferencing application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seven users (7 hosts) in a communication mode https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/product_video?platform=All%20Platforms#key-properties

and

17 users (17 hosts and many audiences) in a Live Broadcast mode https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/product_live?platform=All%20Platforms#key-properties